# How to delete a record when it is nowhere used in multiple other tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, record

I'm making an application in C# and I'm using the EF Code First for my database-creation (for a SQL-Server database).
I have a class "Address" which is used in several other classes.
So several records can relate to the same Address-record. Is there an option in the EF where I can delete the Address-record when it is nowhere used anymore? Unless if I'm wrong, the CascadeOnDelete-option will remove the record once a certain record is deleted while others still relate to the Address-record. 
Also, it wouldn't be very useful to create a new Address-record for each record that relates to it, because most Address-record would be exactly the same (for example, a lot of Address-record would just contain the name of the same country or city).

Sorry if it all sounds a bit fuzzy, I would give some code but I don't really know what code that would be.

Comment: maybe a silly question, but WHY do you want to delete records that aren't used anymore? Storage is pretty cheap, these days... maybe there's another way to achieve your goal without doing it the way you're thinking.

Comment: Hi DrewJordan, I also considered that. The truth is, this project is a personal one so it's wouldn't be that bad. But I'd like to know (if it's possibly done) how it's done the "clean" way so that when I have to do a professional project, I can do it that way. Always nice to say to your client that no unnecessary data is being stored

Comment: gotcha. Then, @Imortist's answer is what you'll have to do. [Here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/08/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-cascade-delete-orphans/) is an example of how to do that inside your save changes, if it helps.

Comment: This looks indeed like something that would be useful but wouldn't you do this each time you persist any object to the database, even if it has nothing to do with the orphaned Address-records? I also read the comments which very pleased me but the problem I have is that I have many parents to one particular child.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, EF doesn't natively provide that feature.

The way I see it, there are a couple of things that you can (should) do to get to your desired result:

First, if you're concerned about duplicate data (Country, City, State, Region, etc.) in an address, you should extract them into their own tables and provide references. This will mean instead of having a varchar of `United States` in `Address.Country` for example, it would be a foreign key of `1` maybe, to the `Countries` table. This isn't a bad idea as it will also allow you to standardize more easily (so you don't get `US`, `U.S.`, and `United States` say).

Second, you can have a business logic layer on top of your database (let's call it `BO`, so when you need to save a Person, you call `PersonBO.Save(Person)`, which interacts with your database on your behalf. Then, extract your check one level further, to a static mainBO class maybe. Your PersonBO (and any other classes that use Addresses) can then call mainBO.FindAndDeleteUnusedAddresses() passing the applicable object (Person person in this case):

```
FindAndDeleteUnusedAddresses(Person person) {
 using (var db = new Entities())
            {
                var personCount = db.Persons.Where(p => p.Address == person.Address).Count();
                var businessCount = db.Businesses.Where(b => b.Address == person.Address).Count();
                // other objects that have addresses here

                if (personCount + businessCount == 0) // others included as necessary
                {
                    db.Entry(person.Address).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how EF behaves when CascadeOnDelete switched off.

It will throw exception on attempt to delete row that is used in any relationship. You will need to catch this exception to show custom message or do something else you need in this case.

If you need to remove Address in a moment when last entity that uses this address deleted it is probably better to check if address is not used in any other places and mark it for deletion manually.

Comment: So if I were to catch the exception and just do nothing inside the catch, it wouldn't bother me when trying to delete a record that is still in use and it would remove the Address-record when the removed record was the only remaining connection, am I right?

Comment: Oh, no, sorry. I didn't understand your task. You will still need to delete your address record manually. CascadeOnDelete works in other way. It will remove dependents on deleting parent entity. In your case you have one-to-many relationship where Address is "one". So CascadeOnDelete will work if you need to remove all entities where address is used when deleting Address entity itself

Comment: Maybe this is a side-question but how would I do this manually? With a script written in my DBMS or via an aggregate DbSet<Address> and then filter out all Address-records used by completely going through all my other aggregates?

Comment: user2226913 Can you post part of your deletion code that you have now?

Comment: I haven't written any code since I wasn't sure if it were to be necessary (because I thought EF had a mechanism build for this sort of thing). But I'll give it a go later this week and I'll be happy to post it if you'd like.